# PHP How to give block of code a parent node

Tags: php, xpath

I have this html structure;
and I need to remove everything after

```
<span class="Title_Blue">
```

or, at least, put the block inside a div. (Then I can manipulate it.)

Is there anyway I can do it with xpath?

I can easily put a tag inside a div, but the problem here is that the code I want to embrace into a div is all at the same level.

Thanks!!

```
<body>
<div class="article_text">
    <div id="text">

        <p class="paragraph">
            <strong> [text] </strong>
        </p>
        <div>
            <strong> [text] </strong>
        </div>
        <strong>
            <br> [Title] <br>
        </strong>
        <div style="text-align: justify;">
            <br> [text]
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: justify;">
            <br> [text]
        </div>

        <span class="Title_Blue"> [text] </span>
        <br>
        <p> ... </p>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>

        <span class="Title_Blue"> [text] </span>
        <br>
        <p> ... </p>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>

        <span class="Title_Blue"> [text] </span>
        <br>
        <p> ... </p>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>
        <div style="text-align: justify;"> [text] </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

EDITED

I tried this:

```
$html = $data
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$contents = $xpath->query('//*[@class="Title_Blue"]');
foreach ($contents as $content) {
    $div = $doc->createElement('div');
    $div->setAttribute('class', 'DELETE_ME');
    $content->parentNode->replaceChild($div, $content);
    $div->appendChild($content);
}
```

EDITED 2

Was able to solve using this code:

```
$html = $data
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$contents = $xpath->query('//*[@class="Title_Blue"] | //*[@class="Title_Blue"]/following-sibling::*');
foreach ($contents as $content) {
    $content->parentNode->removeChild($content);
}
```

Thanks to Andersson!

Comment: did you try anyting?

Comment: You cannot use XPath to *remove everything after*, but you can use it to *select everything after*: `//span[@class="Title_Blue"]/following-sibling::*`

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you! Anyway I can include the original tag? Because it deletes everything "after". //*[@class="Title_Blue"]/following-sibling::* Maybe "and"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to select *everything after `span` including that `span`*, try

```
//span[@class="Title_Blue"]/preceding-sibling::*[1]/following-sibling::*
```